# Elastic search is returning undefined for _id in elastic search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search in my application and everything works fine until you click the search result link which returns `undefined`. The problem I have is that the `_source._id` is returning `undefined`. So I cannot view the search result.

How can I pass the object id in `/blog/article/<%= data[i]._source._id`?

My code is below

> router.js

```
router.post('/search', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/search?q=' + req.body.q);
});

router.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.q) {
    Article.search({
      query_string: { query: req.query.q}
    }, function(err, results) {
      results:
      if (err) return next (err);
      var data = results.hits.hits.map(function(hit) {
        return hit;
      });
      res.render('main/search-result', {
        query: req.query.q,
        data: data
      });
    });
  }
});
```

> search-result.ejs

```
<% for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <a href="/blog/article/<%= data[i]._source._id %>">
             <div class="thumbnail">
               <h3 id="data_title"><%= data[i]._source.title %></h3>
             </div>
         </div>
       <% } %>
```

Comment: p0k8_ do you see anything I am missing in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue by changing

```
<a href="/blog/article/<%= data[i]._source._id %>">
```

to

```
<a href="/blog/article/<%= data[i]._id %>">
```